# Javafx pass login token from LoginController to CalendarController

Tags: javafx

I am using [Angela](https://github.com/acaicedo/JFX-MultiScreen)'s framework for screens management and I am trying to write a very simple **Calendar-application**. While writing the UI and the controllers and using the aforementioned framework, all screens initialize immediately on program start. This means I have no idea when the user is actually looking at a certain view.

I need the *login-token* from the server (assigned in the `LoginController`) to fire a changed value event of some kind in the `CalendarController` that is currently running in the background (I presume). At the moment I don't know when the `Calendar.fxml` is visible and/if the user is logged in, and hence I don't know how to structure my logic to make a function start in `CalendarController` **ONLY** after the *login-token* has been set.

Been stuck a few days here, any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried using an ObservableList and Listlistener-interface to no avail. Here is the respective part of my `LoginController`. TokenFactory is a class of static fields and methods (mostly trying to debug).

```
    @FXML
public boolean login() throws JSONException, UnirestException {
    if(validateUsernameField() && validatePasswordField()) {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.post(TokenFactory.getSERVER_ADR())
          .field("username", usernameField.getText())
          .field("password", passwordField.getText())
          .asJson();
        if ( ((String) jsonResponse.getBody().getObject().get("message")).equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
            String token = ((String) jsonResponse.getBody().getObject().get("token"));
            //Ignore JSON to debug
            TokenFactory.setToken("fakeToken123");  
            responseLabel.setText("Logging in...");
            myController.setScreen(ScreensFramework.CalendarID);
            return true;            
         } else {
            responseLabel.setText("Wrong username or password.");
            passwordField.clear();
        }
    } return false;
}

//Screen management
ScreensController myController;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of options here:

First option: instead of loading all the screens at startup, just load the calendar screen when the login is successful. Then your `CalendarController`'s `initialize()` method can basically assume the user is logged in.

Second option: modify the framework so that it either returns a reference to the controllers when it loads them, or gives you access to the controllers once loaded. The first version of this would look like:

```
public <T extends ControlledScreen> T loadScreen(String name, String resource) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
        Parent loadScreen = (Parent) myLoader.load();
        T myScreenControler = myLoader.getController();
        myScreenControler.setScreenParent(this);
        addScreen(name, loadScreen);
        return myScreenControler ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now when you first load the calendar screen, you can get a reference to its controller:

```
CalendarController calendarController = screensController.loadScreen(...);
```

so now when you are successfully logged in, you can invoke a method on the `calendarController`. Note the return type of `loadScreen(...)` has changed, so you may need to modify other code accordingly.

Alternatively, you could introduce a new map in `ScreensController`:

```
public class ScreensController extends StackPane {

    private Map<String, Node> screens = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, ControlledScreen> controllers = new HashMap<>();

    // ...

    public boolean loadScreen(String name, String resource) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
            Parent loadScreen = (Parent) myLoader.load();
            ControlledScreen myScreenControler = ((ControlledScreen) myLoader.getController());
            myScreenControler.setScreenParent(this);

            addScreen(name, loadScreen);

            // also save the controller:
            controllers.put(name, myScreenControler);

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    // ...

    // new method to retrieve controller:

    public ControlledScreen getController(String name) {
        return controllers.get(name);
    }

    // modify the remove method to clean up the controller as well:

    public boolean unloadScreen(String name) {
        if (screens.remove(name) == null) {
            System.out.println("Screen didn't exist");
            return false;
        } else {
            controllers.remove(name);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when the user logs in, you can do

```
CalendarController calendarController = 
    (CalendarController) myController.getController(ScreensFramework.CalendarID);
```

and invoke whatever method you need on `calendarController`.

Third option: create a `BooleanProperty loggedIn = new SimpleBooleanProperty();` and just set it to `true` when the user is logged in. Then arrange for your `CalendarController` to be able to observe it and react when it changes. I like this option less, because arranging for the `CalendarController` to see the `loggedIn` property will almost certainly involve some kind of additional coupling between that controller and another class, but it is possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up for me. **11/10 reply**. I went for adding another HashMap containing controller-structure. Thanks again, @James_D !